Combine back- and forecast errors for cross-validation
Suppose I have a procedure to predict the timeseries value $Y_{t+k}$, where $t$ is the current period and $k \geq 1, 2, \dots$. Now, I want to estimate the procedure's out-of-sample performance. The model presumes the relationship
\begin{equation}
  Y_t+k = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \left( A_{t+k} * B_{t+k} \right) + \varepsilon_{t+k},
\end{equation}
where $A_{t+k}$ and $B_{t+k}$ are explanatory variables, $\{\beta_0, \beta_1\}$ are parameters to be estimated, and $\varepsilon_{t+k}$ is an arbitrarily distributed error term independent of past or future errors. Suppose $A_{t+k}$ is perfectly known for the future, but $B_{t+k}$ must itself first be forecasted to predict $Y_{t+k}$. A timeseries approach is used to predict both $B_{t+k}$ and $Y_{t+k}$, and the respective estimators read
\begin{equation}
  \hat{B}_{t+l} = p_B(B_{t}, B_{t-1},\dots) \quad \text{and} \quad \hat{Y}_{t+k} = p_Y(Y_{t}, Y_{t-1}, \dots, \hat{B}_{t+k}, B_{t}, B_{t-1},\dots).
\end{equation}
Note the reliance of $\hat{Y}_{t+k}$ on past realizations of the predictand stems from the estimation of the parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ (suppose we use OLS to estimate them).
Question: If I conduct cross-validation with a rolling origin (fixed houldout sample size, successively shifted by one observation to produce up to $k$-step forecasts errors, where $k$ has been fixed beforehand), under which conditions, if any, may I pool $k$-step forecast and $k$-step backcast errors?
My intuition is that the method should be equally able to predict the future and the conditions that precede the future. However, I'd like to make sure my vague intuition is solid.

You did not specify whether your loss was normally distributed, but if it was, you would have something like an ARIMA model. In that case, I am pretty sure that roots below unity magnitude for forecasting, those that lead to stationary behavior, would be above unity for backcasting. I am therefore not sure you can forecast equally well in both directions.

In any case, why not generate some data and see whether your intuition will be supported by empirical results?

Another way of thinking about it is this. Stationary time-series would have a behavior where irrespective of some past random displacement from the mean, you will still converge to some stationary distribution close to the mean in the future. Now turn this around, and run time backward. Even if you start with the same stationary distribution now, you can backcast to a wide range of large random displacements in the past. Behavior is divergent.
